# Javascript part of the code is not posted to the database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to enter data to my database with dynamic textboxes. The dynamic textboxes are created with Javascript. When I try to send the data to my database I see that my PHP script is posting only the first row into the database

```
<div id="form">
  <form name="reaction" id="reaction" method="post" action="./post.php">
  //The first row is created in HTML
  <input type="text" name="firstname[]" id="firstname1" placeholder="Firstname" /> <br />
</div>

//The other rows are created in Javascript
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    var final_total_amt = $('#final_total_amt').text();
    var count = 1;

  $(document).on('click', '#add_row', function(){
    count++;
    $('#total_item').val(count);
    var html_code = '';
    html_code += '<input type="text" placeholder="Firstname'+count+'" name="firstname[]" id="firstname'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" /><br />';
  });

  $('#form').append(html_code);
</script>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="send">Save</button>
</form>
```

In the PHP script I am trying to post the multiple textboxes with:

```
foreach($_POST['firstname'] as $i => $item) {
  $db3 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'root', 'pass');
  $query3= "INSERT INTO scu_db(firstname) VALUES (:firstname)";
  $stmt3 = $db3->prepare($query3);
  $exec3 = $stmt3->execute(array(
    ':firstname'     =>  $_POST["firstname"][$i]
  ));
}
```

The script only posts the first row that is created in HTML to my database.

Does someone know how I can solve this?

Result of `var_dump` on `$_POST['firstname']`:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "1" }
```

Comment: kidnly upload the foreach full code

Comment: I updated my post with the foreach full code

Comment: first echo only `$item` if you are receiving multiple data comment your insertion for a while

Comment: try inserting with $item... .. have your dumped? $_POST? can you edit it and upload the result

Comment: if you are receiving correct data then assigned your `$item` to your `:firstname`

Comment: I get a `Notice: Undefined offset: 1` when I use `$item` instead of `$i`. Data `1` in this case is the firstname that is entered in the first row.

Comment: Result of var_dump on $_POST['firstname']: `array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "1" }` 1 in this case is the data I entered in the textbox `firstname`

Comment: I dont think that there is something wrong with the PHP part (foreach) of the code. The code works when I use multiple HTML textboxes. The code doesnt work when de HTML part is created in Javascript

Comment: Try echo this `$item['firstname'];`

Comment: When I echo `$item['firstname'];` I get `1`

Comment: Before foreach use push() function and see if it gives multiple data like this `$item = push($_POST["firstname"]);` just echo $item before foreach

Comment: How can I define the function push() function?

Comment: we use it in php, try to do this `var html_code = [];` instead of this `' '`

Comment: and do `var_dump` again, if it doesn't work then remove `+` and just leave `=` to assign your code to `[]`

Comment: When I change the `html_code` to `var html_code = [];` I still get `array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "name1" }`. When I delete `+` and just leave `=` I can not add new rows anymore.

Comment: try this if it helps `$('#form').val(append(html_code));` or this `$('#form').append(val(html_code));`

Comment: No. Adding new rows is still not working

Comment: Let me try it at home.

Comment: also try this `$(document).on('click',` replace it with this `$('#form').on('click',`

Comment: @AkhtarMunir it didnt work :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184218/discussion-between-john-and-akhtar-munir).

Comment: there's a `});` missing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem was caused primarily by improperly nested HTML tags. Switch the positions of your `div#form` tag with your `form` like below

```
<form name="reaction" id="reaction" method="post" action="./post.php">
  <div id="form">
```

Remember to close out your `$(document).ready()` method declaration, and also place your `$('#form').append(html_code)` code within the scope of your `$(document).on('click')` event.

See below for a working sample

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>

<form name="reaction" id="reaction" method="post" action="">
<div id="form">
  //The first row is created in HTML
  <input type="text" name="firstname[]" id="firstname1" placeholder="Firstname" /> <br />
</div>

//The other rows are created in Javascript
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var final_total_amt = $('#final_total_amt').text();
  var count = 1;

  $(document).on('click', '#add_row', function(){
    count++;
    $('#total_item').val(count);
    var html_code = '';
    html_code += '<input type="text" placeholder="Firstname'+count+'" name="firstname[]" id="firstname'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" /><br />';
    $('#form').append(html_code);
  });
});
</script>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="send">Save</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add_row">Add Row</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

@John in my case I had done it like this, it is working fine. It has two buttons to add and/or remove fields from the other fields. If you need this then I can send you both files in email.

```
 addNewRow();

$("#add").click(function(){
    addNewRow();
})

function addNewRow(){
    $.ajax({
        url : DOMAIN+"/includes/process.php",
        method : "POST",
        data : {getNewOrderItem:1},
        success : function(data){
            $("#invoice_item").append(data);
            var n = 0;
            $(".number").each(function(){
                $(this).html(++n);
            })
        }
    })
}

$("#remove").click(function(){
    $("#invoice_item").children("tr:last").remove();
})
```